# Declaring and using variables in same line (Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Can you explain line 11 and 12? In these lines, the author is declaring `TrendUp` and `TrendDown` variables and instantly using it? On that basis what is the initial value of these variables? Please expain whole lines 11 and 12 (below) 
`TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up`. 
`TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn` 
Thanks!

```
study("vbm_Buy or Sell Signal", overlay = true)

Factor=input(3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(7, minval=1,maxval = 100)


Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))


TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
MACD = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? blue : red

plot(MACD, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "B/S")

plotshape(cross(close,MACD) and close>MACD , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,blue,0,0)
plotshape(cross(MACD,close) and close<MACD , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
//plot(Trend==1 and Trend[1]==-1,color = linecolor, style = circles, linewidth = 3,title="Trend")

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=blue, maxheight=40, minheight=30, transp=0)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=40, minheight=30, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very first bar, `TrendUp[1]` and `close[1]` will be `na` because there are no historical values yet.

Therefore, on the very first bar, `close[1]>TrendUp[1]` will be `false` and `TrendUp` will get the value of `Up`.

So, initially, `TrendUp` will be equal to `Up`.

Comment: Will it be possible if you could explain all conditions in this code. Please!

Comment: What is not clear to you?

Comment: `TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up`. In this line, initially we've TrendUp = Up. On that note the, will MACD in line 15 `MACD = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown` also be equal to Up?

Since they're interdependent, what will be value of MACD for TrendUp condition?